# Python global variables unexpected behavior

Tags: python, module, global-variables

I am finding a discrepancy I did not expect in the Python (3.8) example below.

We define a global variable in module `config`:

`config.py`:

```
global_variable = 80
```

Then two functions in module `foo` using that global variable in two different ways that I expected to be equivalent:

`foo.py`:

```
from config import global_variable
import config

def foo1():
    return global_variable


def foo2():
    return config.global_variable
```

Finally, I print the result of both functions after setting the global variable to `0` in a main script:

`main.py`:

```
import config
import foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config.global_variable = 0
    print("foo1(): ", foo.foo1())
    print("foo2(): ", foo.foo2())
```

but I find them to have different results. The output is:

```
foo1():  80
foo2():  0
```

How is that difference explained?

Comment: `global_variable` gives you the value and `config.global_variable` gives you reference

Comment: Each module has its own global namespace. Importing adds a new binding to the current module's globals.

Comment: @gilch, yes, but the new binding introduced by "from config import global_variable" might conceivably still refer to config.global_variable (sharing its value). It seems to do more than creating a new binding, it creates an entirely new variable initialized by the value of config.global_variable but separate from it.

Comment: No, it's a new reference to the same object. If it were a mutable object (like a dict), then mutations would be visible from both references. But your assignment changes where the reference is pointing, which doesn't affect the other one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the previous answers and comments. They helped me understand the issue but I feel that none of them is completely clear, so here is an answer.

When I asked the question, I though that `from config import global_variable` would create a new binding (or "name") `global_variable` in the local package, but which would still bind to the same memory location as `config.global_variable` (two names for the same variable).

However, what seems to be true is that `from config import global_variable` creates a new variable `global_variable` in the local package, merely *initialized* by the value of `config.global_variable`. (To be more precise, for efficiency reasons `global_variable` probably still points to the same memory location as `config.global_variable` when it is created but, unlike a normal binding, it starts referring to some other memory location when assigned a new value).

For this reason, when I assign a new value to `global_variable`, I do not affect `config.global_variable` as originally expected, but instead change the value of the new variable `global_variable`.

So it seems that if I want a variable to be used across modules, I must always use the qualified form `config.global_variable` in all of them.

Answer (score 1):

It's the way you used your import statements. You imported the same file twice in different manners so python also treats them as two imports. So when you change the value for the variable as

```py
config.global_variable = 0
```

It affects the global variable of

```py
import config
```

this import statement in your `foo.py` file.

```py
from config import global_variable
import config

def foo1():
    return global_variable # uses from config import global_variable statement


def foo2():
    return config.global_variable # uses import config
```

Hence in here, foo2() returns the changed variable's value but foo1() returns the original. If you want to change foo1()'s value then you must do something like this.

```py
from config import global_variable
import config
import foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    config.global_variable = 0
    global_variable = 0
    print("foo1(): ", foo.foo1())
    print("foo2(): ", foo.foo2())
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm probably just as new at this as you are, but I'm pretty sure a variable is only global if the global declaration is in the script you're importing to